# Highcharts: How to set colors per column, per series, with a data set, in a multi series chart?

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I am using the `@types` since my code is within a `.ts` file.

I have a chart that uses a column and a line series. My data returns the color code that needs to be sent to the chart. How can I apply this, so that each column has a specific color that I set with my data?

Certain columns will be red for example, while the rest are blue. The red indicates to pay attention to this bar etc. The line chart color needs to stay default, or whatever color I would like. Using the `plotOptions.column.colorByPoint = true` then adding to the `colors:{}` array sets them globally, which affects the line chart.

Setting them within the `chart.series:[]` only works if you want one color for the entire series and only accepts a `string`, not an array of any kind.

The reference seems to hint that you can use `colors:{}` within a `chart.series:[]` but I get the following error when I try:

> ```
> Object literal may only specify known properties, 
>   but 'colors' does not exist in type 'IndividualSeriesOptions'. 
>   Did you mean to write 'color'?
> ```

I seem to have exhausted all my luck looking for a super customizable option. We previously used Logi, which did this for us SOMEHOW

Comment: I just try in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwqeau4L/) and everything works. I think the problem is from the library.

Comment: Wow. You're right. I am guessing the `@types` aren't up to date.... thanks a million @Core972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I was having was because of `@types/highcharts`. It is out of date, and starting with v7 of Highcharts, this will no longer be an issue.

In the meantime, people looking for better typings, can visit [this beta typing declaration](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-declarations-beta). For some questions on how to use the new `interface` declarations, there is some Q/A going on [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-declarations-beta/issues/8).